# Excel macro date formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-format

I have an excel sheet that puts in the current date and time in a specific cell if a macro is ran. It formats the date and time in the format dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm. For the whole month March this worked perfectly. However, now in April, it suddenly outputs the dates as mm-dd-yyyy HH:mm.

What could a cause for this be?

This is the code:

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Long


For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Status = Cells(i, 1).Value

If Status = "Status1" And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 12).Value) = True Then
Cells(i, 12).Value = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy HH:mm")

ElseIf Status = "Status2" And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 13).Value) = True Then
Cells(i, 13).Value = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy HH:mm")

ElseIf Status = "Status3" And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 14).Value) = True Then
Cells(i, 14).Value = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy HH:mm")

ElseIf Status = "Status4" And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 15).Value) = True Then
Cells(i, 15).Value = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy HH:mm")

ElseIf Status = "Status5 " And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 16).Value) = True Then
Cells(i, 16).Value = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy HH:mm")

ElseIf Status = "Status6" And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 17).Value) = True Then
Cells(i, 17).Value = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy HH:mm")

ElseIf Status = "Status7" Then
Cells(i, 18).Value = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy HH:mm")

End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share the VBA code you have used so far, will help us to fix the issue.

Comment: Probably an issue with the macro, and possibly the formatting of your worksheet and your Windows Regional Settings.

Comment: Unable to understand that Y U r testing so may STATUS for same DATE TIME Format !!

Comment: It is a drop down menu and when the status is changed the current date needs to be placed in a specific cell.

Comment: I've tried this `Cells(i, 12) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Now(), "dd-mm-yy hh:mm")` working properly .

Comment: It still outputs it in the mm-dd-yyyy format. What could the problem be? The strange part is that in March it was formatting it correctly.